# Can't we have extension methods with same name for different classes?

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I have two extension methods like this..

One is

```
   public static BsonValue TopOne(this IEnumerable<BsonValue> IEnumBv)
   {

   }
```

Second One is

```
 public static BsonValue TopOne(this BsonValue IEnumBv)
 {

 }
```

Is this not possible ? I am not getting reason.

Even name are same but its for different Extensions methods right ?

Or how to achieve this ? I need topone name for both the extensions.Is it possible ?

**UPDATE**

I am getting this error

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'BsonExtensionLibrary.MongoExtensions.TopOne(MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue)' and 'BsonExtensionLibrary.MongoExtensions.TopOne(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Have you tried to compile your code?

Comment: yeah its not compiling.. It says name is ambigous between both.

Comment: sorry its spelling mistake yaar.. IEnumerable fine..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can absolutely do this - but you'll have problems if you try to call the extension method on something which is both a `BsonValue` *and* an `IEnumerable<BsonValue>`. For example:

```
BsonArray array = ...;
BsonValue top = array.TopValue();
```

Which method would you expect to be called? Both are applicable, and neither conversion is better than the other.

Note that this has nothing to do with extension methods really - it's just overload resolution. You'd face exactly the same problem if those were normal static methods, and you had:

```
BsonArray array = ...;
BsonValue top = BsonHelpers.TopValue(array);
```

Either give the two methods different names, or find some way of expressing what you want, e.g.

```
BsonArray array = ...;
BsonValue topAsEnumerable = array.AsEnumerable().TopValue();
BsonValue topAsValue = ((BsonValue) array).TopValue();
```

(That's using the `Enumerable.AsEnumerable` extension method *just* to convert the expression type to `IEnumerable<BsonValue>`.)

Comment: Caveat: If you have two extension methods with the same name but accepting different parameter types, callers will need to reference the assemblies of each of those parameter types, even though they will only use one specifically. This has the surprising effect that when you add a new overload with its own type, the code calling the original extension method is suddenly broken - it needs to reference the type of the new overload to establish which choice is best.